# Completion of a non-Galois extension

Tags: number-theory, local-field

The discussion in these posts, [Completions of number fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713463/completions-of-number-fields) and [Corresponding local extension does not depend on choice of prime ideal above?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525756/corresponding-local-extension-does-not-depend-on-choice-of-prime-ideal-above), gets at the fact that if $L/K$ is a Galois extension of number fields and $P,Q$ are primes of $L$ both above a prime $p$ in $K$, then there is an isomorphism $L_P \cong L_Q$ as local field extensions of $K_p$.

When $L/K$ is not Galois, this can fail to be true. But in all the example I have seen so far, the primes $P,Q$ above $p$ have different ramification/residue field indexes.

**Question:** If $L/K$ is a non-Galois extension of number fields and $P,Q$ are prime ideals of $L$, both above a prime ideal $p$ of K, which have the same residue degree and ramification index, is it the case $L_Q \cong L_P$ as fields over $K_p$?

For example, when $L/K$ is not Galois, $[L:K]=n$, and $p O_L = P_1 P_2 ... P_n$ (i.e. $p$ is totally split in $L$), are the extensions $L_{P_i}/K_p$ ($i=1,...,n$) all isomorphic as field extensions of $K_p$?

**Edit:** I think in this second, $p$ totally split in $L$, case $[L_{P_i}:K_p] = e(P_i/p)f(P_i/p)=1$, so all the $L_{P_i}$s  are $K_p$.

Comment: @user297024 your example works by adding just $8$: $h(x)=(x^2+1)(x^2-2)+8=x^4 -x^2 +6$ is irred. over $\mathbf Q$ since it is irred. mod $11$. In $\mathbf Z_2[x]$, $g(x) := x^2-x+6$ is reducible since its discriminant is $-23 \equiv 1 \bmod 8$: it factors as $(x-r)(x-s)$ with $r=2+2^3 +2^5 +\cdots$ and $s=1+2 +2^2 +2^3 +2^4 +\cdots$, so $r\equiv 2\bmod 8$ and $s\equiv 7\equiv -1\bmod 8$. As $r$ and $s$ aren't $2$-adic squares, $h(x)=g(x^2)=(x^2-r)(x^2-s)$ is an irred. $2$-adic factorization, so  $(2)=P^2 Q^2$, $K_P =\mathbf Q_2(r)=\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$, $K_Q=\mathbf Q_2(s)=\mathbf Q_2(i)$.

Comment: @user297024 Sure. But the OP wrote "in all the example I have seen so far...", suggesting an example is worth displaying. By the way, your example works *accidentally* by adding $4$: when $h(x)=(x^2+1)(x^2-2)+4=x^4 - x^2 +2$, it's irred. over $\mathbf Q$ since it's irred. mod $3$. And $g(x) := x^2 -x+2$ has discriminant $-7\equiv 1 \bmod 8$ with $2$-adic roots $r\equiv 6\bmod 8$ and $s\equiv 3\bmod 8$, so $h(x)=g(x^2)=(x^2-r)(x^2-s)$: $(2)=P^2Q^2$ with $K_P=\mathbf Q_2(r)=\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{6})$ (not $\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{2})$) and $K_Q=\mathbf Q_2(s)=\mathbf Q_2(\sqrt{3})$ (not $\mathbf Q_2(i)$).